# Question on incidence matrix associated with dominance relation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For any incidence matrix(denote A)that has the property $A_{ij}= 1 $ if and only if $ A_{ji} = 0 $. Also known as the dominance relation I guess.  There is a corollary that the matrix $ A + A^2$ has a row column in which each entry is positive except the one on the diagonal. In other words, there is at least one person who dominants all others in one or two stages. I have no clues about how to prove this, can somebody help